# C# How to manually control RTS/CTS using the SerialPort class

Tags: c#, serial-port, handshake

Please let me know if you know.

I'm developing a modem tester in C# using the SerialPort class.

Is there a way to manually control RTS/CTS without using System.IO.Ports.Handshake#RequestToSend?

The flow of data Send/Receive is as follows.

0. Open SerialPort.

---

1. Set to RTS "High"
2. Wait for CTS to go "High".
3. Send any byte data after CTS goes "High".
4. After the data transmission is complete, set to RTS "Low"

---

5. Wait to receive data from the other side.
6. Receive data from the other side.

Repeat steps 1 to 6.

My understanding is below.
・The method to set RTS to High is SerialPort#RtsEnable = true
・CTS High is SerialPort#CtsHolding = true

As a trial, I wired the RS232C cable so that the output of the RTS signal was input to the CTS signal.
I verified the code below using this RS232C cable, but SerialPort#CtsHolding does not become true and times out.

Even if SerialPort#RtsEnable is set to true, does RTS not go "High"?
(Should I use Win32API...?)

```
    public class SerialCommunicationTester : System.IDisposable
    {
        private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort _serialPort = null;

        // 0. Open SerialPort.
        public bool Open(
            string portName,
            int baudRate,
            int dataBits,
            System.IO.Ports.Parity parity,
            System.IO.Ports.StopBits stopBits,
            int readTimeout,
            int writeTimeout,
        ) {
            _serialPort.PortName = portName;
            _serialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
            _serialPort.DataBits = dataBits;
            _serialPort.Parity = parity;
            _serialPort.StopBits = stopBits;
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = readTimeout;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = writeTimeout;

            try {
                _serialPort.Open();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("SerialPort#Open Failed...{0}", ex);
            }

            return _serialPort.IsOpen;
        }

        // 1. Set to RTS "High" and 2. Wait for CTS to go "High".
        public bool RtsCtsFlowCtrl(uint timeout) {

            if (!_serialPort.IsOpen) return false;

            bool result = true;
            // 1. Set to RTS "High"
            _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            // 2. Wait for CTS to go "High".
            while (true) {
                Thread.Sleep(0);
                if (_serialPort.CtsHolding) break;
                if (0 < timeout && timeout <= sw.ElapsedMilliseconds) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            return result;
        }

        // 4. Set to RTS "Low"
        public void RtsOff() {
            if (_serialPort.IsOpen) _serialPort.RtsEnable = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have set Handshake to None - that will cause the serial port to have no flow control, so maybe it doesn't bother to set CtsHolding as it is not used. Try setting Handshake to RequestToSend - that will enable RTS/CTS control.

Comment: @PaulF , that explanation is for the setting when you want to control the signal line with a device driver, which is different from the intention of the question. The question states that the application explicitly wants to control the RTS. [internal bool RtsEnable](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/sys/system/IO/ports/SerialStream.cs#L458)